# Getting mod_write rules in the Server Config context to apply to all sites

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Long time reader, first time poster.

I've got some rewrite rules that work fine within a virtualhost context, but I can't get it to apply at the server config context, which I want to do so it applies to ALL virtual hosts.

The directives:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?cgi-sys/defaultwebpage\.cgi$ / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried altering it to not enforce the start and end as such:

```
 RewriteRule cgi-sys/defaultwebpage\.cgi / [R=301,L]
```

But I can't trigger it.

What am I missing?

Apache/2.2.13

As asked in the comments, the user is entering:

```
 http://www.example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi
```

The following log entry results:

```
 203.4.5.6 - - [05/Apr/2011:10:23:16 +1000] "GET /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 26 "-"
 "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko)
 Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27"
```

Now, the site in question has an .htaccess file with this rule that I believe is intercepting this request:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

I temporarily disabled that directive, and then apache just served a vanilla 404:

```
 203.45.73.63 - - [05/Apr/2011:10:27:28 +1000] "GET /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" 
 "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
 Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27"
```

Comment: Can you provide example of full URL please -> What does the client type, what does the client see, what file the client is served?

Comment: The client types http://www.example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi and the client receives a 404 error.

Comment: Updated the question with some further information and examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand of your rules:

client writes `example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` the rule match and redirect on `/` that will direct to `index.php` by rewritting of the last rule.

Does the file `example.com/index.php` exists?

Comment: But the rule features [R=301], so should be redirected, and [L] meaning that further rules shouldn't be processed. If I query the headers of the first request, I get "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", so that first RewriteRule is seemingly not being processed.

Comment: [L] prevent other rules to apply, but does not avoid the rules to be run again when the broser ask for the new page (with rewritten URL)

Comment: But I'm never getting the URL rewritten by virtue of the fact I'm being served a 200, not a 301.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you've reloaded the server config files after doing this? You don't have to in per-directory rules but you do here.